# getting error 400 with axios post request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

I am trying to make a post request using axios to fetch a key from a server and use it to make a second post request. the first one should return a variable called session_id, which it does, but the second request fails with error code 400, Bad Request. I have tried adding a delay to the second request, in case it was a problem with the promise, but it did not work. Sorry if this is a stupid mistake, as i am new to working with JS calls. If it would be benificial for me to post the entire code, ask, and i will do so.

```
async function login() {
  await axios.post(url,credentials)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.data.data.sessionId
        })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    })
}

function pullPush(sessionId) {
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Session ' + sessionId
      axios.post(url2, body)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
pullPush(login())
```

Comment: `login` a promise that resolves to undefined - because you haven't returned any value in that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using async incorrectly Try `login().then(pullPush)`
and return the axios.post call within the login function.

So `return await axios.post(...)`

Since login is an async function it returns a promise.
So we chain it with `then` to get the results of the last chained `.then`
and pass it the next function which `pullPush`